# Why does my phone sometimes unlock with TouchID, but not go to home screen/app?

Tags: iphone, ios, touch-id

I have an iPhone 7 running iOS 11.0.1. I just started using TouchID to unlock the phone, and I've occasionally encountered an unexpected behavior.

I thought that when pressing the home button it would unlock and go to the home screen, or last app. I have on multiple occasions pressed the home button to find myself at the lock screen, with the "Press home to open" message at the bottom, and the lock missing at the top. I can't seem to replicate this with any consistency.

The end result is exactly as if I pressed the hold button to wake the phone, and then touched the home button to unlock.

**Is there some specific way that I'm pressing the home button to cause this?**

I would prefer this behavior to opening to my last app because my natural grip on the phone makes it easier to press the home button than the hold button, and I like to check notifications on the lock screen.

Comment: If you want to look at the lock-screen, use a fingernail, not a registered fingerprint... or press the sleep/wake button instead... or just use 'raise to wake'.

Comment: A fingernail will not work. The other options would work, but the bring their own problems.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using raise to wake? There is a timing that is difficult to duplicate, but can be repeated, where you can press the home button and raise to wake at the same time. The Touch ID unlocks the phone, but the wake seems to register from the raise instead of the home button press and so you stay on the lock screen instead of opening to the last app/home screen.

If you want the behavior of the phone being unlocked, but staying on the lock screen so you can look at your notifications, then just raise to wake, rest your finger on the home button, but don’t press until you’re ready to leave the lock screen.

Comment: I’m not using raise to wake, but it does feel like the behavior is tied to me moving the phone first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first there are Two options to view your screen “not unlock”

The first one is raise to wake enabled here you view the screen by raising the phone and unlock with home botton.
The second is with raise to wake disabled here you view the screen with the first home botton click and unlock with the second. 
So if you want to unlock the phone directly with one home botton click you must enable raise to wake in settings.

I hope this finds you well.